# How to convert date in Stata?

Tags: stata, datetime

I have a date with a format like below, and I use R to convert it from string to date

```
date <- "20 Nov 2010 21:44:00:000"
strptime(date,"%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I want to do it in Stata, but how? I tried this in Stata:

```
gen time_2 = date(time,"DMYhms#")
```

But it's not OK, why is that? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/modules/dates.htm

Comment: What does "not OK" mean?  Why do you have the # in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `date` function converts dates expressed in days, months and years. For timestamps containing hours and seconds, you need the `clock` function. The new variable should be in double precision

```
gen double time_2 = clock(time,"DMYhms#")
```